# How can I determine if a Network Stream timed out?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a TCP client and I set the network stream timeout as follows.

```
stream.ReadTimeout = 60000;
```

It works. But I would like to know how to test if the stream timed out. The class doesn't provide this method.

A little more detail to the question.
I am sending data to a TCPListener, about 33KB every 30 minutes. Typically, the transmission lasts about 10s and the client issues a manual "DISCONNECT" command to causes the Listener to start again. The client is an embedded system using a 3G module and sometimes the network connectivity causes the link to break. Right now, I am simply setting a read timeout of 60s. If we do not get data during that time, we simply restart the listener and wait for the next connection.
I am logging the performance of the system and would like to know how many timeouts typically occur in, say, one week. It'd have been good for the listener to simply check if the read operation time out, but I do not see a way of doing it easily in C#.
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are sending ascii data terminate the data with a character that is not in the data.  With binary data include a byte count at the beginning of the message.  Then you do not have to restart the listener.  You do not mormally do timeouts on streams since you may not get continuous data.  Normally at the listener you capture the close event so when the client closes connection you can stop the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand the problem about logging. I would look for the Read operation's return value, because if that is 0, a timeout occured for sure. And before I reinitialized the listener I would put a logging logic that logs the fact of the timeout. Please tell me if I misunderstood the concept of your program.